# Is there a python function (preferably seaborn) that can help me connect two sets of points with a line on a scatterplot?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

```
Index   X1  Y1  X2  Y2

0       3   2    7   8

1      -5   5    4  -6

…       …   …   …   …

n       6  -3   5   -1
```

Is there a way to create a scatterplot with a line connecting `(x1, y1)` to `(x2, y2)` for each row in the index? (i.e `(3,2)` needs to connect to `(7,8), (-5, 5)` needs to connect to `(4,-6)` and so on for each row. The data set I am using has hundreds of rows and I need to connect each pair of points with a line.

My preferred library would be on Seaborn.

The expected results should include a scatterplot with each pair of points connected with a line. Since there will be hundreds of lines on the scatterplot, I need to plot this using reduced line weights and transparency.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a double melt, combined with `sns.lineplot`:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# generate identification column
df['id'] = df.index

# combine all X values in a column. Same for Y values
df_x = df.melt(id_vars='id', value_vars=['X1', 'X2']).rename(columns={'value':'X'})[['id', 'X']]
df_y = df.melt(id_vars='id', value_vars=['Y1', 'Y2']).rename(columns={'value':'Y'})[['Y']]

# combine X-values, Y-values, and identification column
temp = pd.concat([df_x, df_y], axis=1)

# use lineplot, with different lines for each id:
sns.lineplot(x='X', y='Y', hue='id', data=temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw you asked preferably for `seaborn` but if necessary it can also be done in a few lines of code with only `matplotlib` and its [`LineCollection`](https://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.LineCollection) :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

# DataFrame provided in example:
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'X1': [3, -5, 6], 'Y1': [2, 5, -3], 'X2': [7, 4, 5], 'Y2': [8, -6, -1]})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Plot the (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) points in different colors
ax.scatter(df['X1'], df['Y1'], color='navy', s=100, lw=0, zorder=5)
ax.scatter(df['X2'], df['Y2'], color='darkorange', s=100, lw=0, zorder=6)

# Create the segments coordinates :
segments = df.T.apply(lambda x: [(x.loc['X1'], x['Y1']), (x['X2'], x['Y2'])])
# Use them in a LineCollection
lc = LineCollection(segments, zorder=4, cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
# Set different linewidth if necessary :
lc.set_linewidths(np.random.random_sample(size=len(segments)) * 2)
ax.add_collection(lc)
```

[image: result]